Unable to create Leaflet map with Natural Earth data
I am trying and failing to successfully use Natural Earth data to make leaflet maps. Here is what I tried
$ curl -L -O https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.zip
$ unzip -o ne_50m_admin_0_countries.zip
$ ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp
$ tippecanoe -zg -pC -o ne_50m_admin_0_countries.mbtiles --drop-densest-as-needed ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson

and this is how my l
Leaflet map looks with two layers, the GeoJSON layer from Geo-Maps repo on Github in b&w that look fine, and the Natural Earth data in blue that is all off.

Thinking that perhaps I messed up the projection, I tried rerunning tippecanoe with -sEPSG:3857 but that gave me a blank canvas.
What am I doing wrong?
From @TomazicM, I know that I am at least using the correct flag -pC with tippecanoe to ensure the tiles are not compressed and can be handled by Leaflet (specifically, Leaflet.VectorGrid plugin)

GeoJSON should be CRS84 (there is no EPSG code for it).   It's decimal degrees in longitude/latitude order, that's not EPSG:3587 which is metres Eastings and Northings

right, makes sense. Which is why I got a blank canvas on my second attempt. The question still remains, why is the first attempt (image shown above) the way it is?

figured it out. Since I am using tiles, I need the following option in my tile layer. It works now
tms: true

I take it all back. All of below was because of "user error". To summarize, the following works
    `L.vectorGrid.protobuf(url,{ tms: true }).addTo(map);`


Gah! I spoke too soon. While the above option fixed "ne_50m_admin_0_countries", the layer "ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines" constructed in exactly the same way continues to display flipped. In the image below, both layers are from "natural earth" but the water features tiles continue to display off.

